# GEE's geometry doesn't cover all multipolygons when setting geodesic as false and projection as null

Tags: google-earth-engine

I created 6 geometries with identical coordinates but with different settings of `projection` and `geodesic`. The coordinates I used is composed of two polygons. Then I use `reduceRegion` to print out the minimum and maximum latitude and longitudes.

The weird result is that when I do not specify the projection, and specify true for the `geodesic` parameter, the resulting range of latitude and longitude only covered the first polygon. On the other hand, the result for with `projection` specified as EPSG:4326 and `geodeisc` specified as true covered both polygons. But the [GEE's documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-polygon) states:

> The default is the projection of the inputs, where Numbers are assumed
> to be EPSG:4326.

Which suggest that the two results should have been the same.

I also considered the possibility that GEE uses a pull-based method for projection and scale, so I tested results with the projection specified to be the same as that of the reducer (EPSG:4269). But they covered both polygons as well.

Note that when I plot all of the geometries (whether EPSG:4326, EPSG:4269, null) using `Map.addLayer`, they all looked the same.
Also note that when I specify `geodesic` as false, both polygons are covered as well.

Below is my code:

```
var coords = [
  [[-140, 54], [-130, 54], [-130, 60], [-140, 60], [-140, 54]],
  [[-125, 28], [-72, 28], [-72, 50], [-125, 50], [-125, 28]]
  ]

var geometry4326Geodesic = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(coords, 'EPSG:4326', true)
var geometry4326Planner = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(coords, 'EPSG:4326', false)
var geometry4269Geodesic = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(coords, 'EPSG:4269', true)
var geometry4269Planner = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(coords, 'EPSG:4269', false)
var geometryNullGeodesic = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(coords, null, true)
var geometryNullPlanner = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(coords, null, false)


var lonLat = ee.Image.pixelLonLat()

var reducers = ee.Reducer.count().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.min(),
  sharedInputs: true
}).combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.max(),
  sharedInputs: true
})

var GEE = function(geometry, title){
  var result = lonLat.reduceRegion({
    reducer:reducers,
    geometry:geometry,
    crs:'EPSG:4269',
    scale: 5000
  })
  Map.addLayer(geometry, {}, title)
  print(title, result)
}

// same results are noted with the same alphabet. A and B are different but both roughly cover two polygons. C only cover 
GEE(geometry4326Geodesic, '4326_geodesic')// A
GEE(geometry4326Planner, '4326_palnner')// B
GEE(geometry4269Geodesic, '4269_geodesic')// A
GEE(geometry4269Planner, '4269_planner')// B
GEE(geometryNullGeodesic, 'null_geodesic')// C
GEE(geometryNullPlanner, 'null_planner')// B
```

Comment: Yup, that's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug report and Google has replied. The example I gave in the bug report was slightly different, but the mistake is the same: **I missed a set of brackets for each polygon, so GEE think they are the same polygon with holes instead of separate polygons.**

The bug report I filed and Google's full reply is [here](http://The%20code%20has%20a%20MultiPolygon%20definition%20that%20is%20missing%20a%20set%20of%20brackets%20around%20each%20polygon)